# GalleryView Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement [this](http://spaceforaname.com/panels.html) JqueryGallery to my website(*big gray box*). Now my problem is that the images doesn't appear.

Here my [website](http://www.testground.idghosting.com/pixa/)

**here is my header code:**

```
<link href="css/galleryview.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleryview-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.timers-1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#photos').galleryView({
            panel_width: 655,
            panel_height: 336,
            transition_speed: 1500,
            transition_interval: 5000,
            nav_theme: 'dark',
            border: '1px solid white',
            pause_on_hover: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is my gallery code:**

```
<div id="photos" class="galleryview">
<div class="panel">
     <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/01.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">

      <h2>Effet du soleil sur le paysage</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/tomharry" target="_blank">tomharry</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/158829" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
     <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/02.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">

      <h2>Eden</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/emsago" target="_blank">emsago</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/152865" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
     <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/03.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">

      <h2>Snail on the Corn</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/baines" target="_blank">baines</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/34453" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
     <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/04.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">

      <h2>Flowers</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/jazza" target="_blank">jazza</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/990169" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
     <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/06.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">

      <h2>Alone Beach 2B</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/sgursozlu" target="_blank">sgursozlu</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/738279" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you see it on my website or in the sample page of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you figured it out. But just for your information, to take advantage of the new script 2.1.1: your code should look like:

```
<ul id="photos" class="galleryview">
  <li>
    <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/01.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">
      <h2>Effet du soleil sur le paysage</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/tomharry" target="_blank">tomharry</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/158829" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/02.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">
      <h2>Eden</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/emsago" target="_blank">emsago</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/152865" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/03.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">
      <h2>Snail on the Corn</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/baines" target="_blank">baines</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/34453" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://spaceforaname.com/img/gallery/04.jpg" /> 
    <div class="panel-overlay">
      <h2>Flowers</h2>
      <p>Photo by <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/profile/jazza" target="_blank">jazza</a>.  View full-size photo <a href="http://www.sxc.hu/photo/990169" target="_blank">here</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the code is cleaner and it's more HTML-wise semantically correct (look up on [*Divitis*](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/web_development_mistakes/)) so it might be worth upgrading. :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem it was a conflict between 2 scripts..